# Debugging wifi connection on Nexus 5x

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-5x, debug

After upgrading from Nexus 5 to Nexus 5X, I am unable to connect to my company's wifi. The credentials I provide are correct, and sometimes I do manage to connect, but that lasts only several seconds to minutes.

The wifi screen shows the wifi with "Saved", which then goes through "Connecting", "Authenticating" and back to "Saved".

How can I debug this and see what is happening? Is there a log I can investigate? All other wifis have no problems so far.

Thanks

Comment: Check with the network admin. Sounds like there's a MAC filter in place which doesn't let you in, as your new device's MAC hasn't yet been entered into the whitelist.

Comment: My previous phone was also my personal device, and I don't recall giving anyone my MAC address. Also, this wifi is public, for guests to connect to with only a password, it does not expose our internal network. I will check with them just in case they have already had a similar issue.

Comment: Also, as I have noted but perhaps didn't emphasize, I sometimes connect to the wifi shortly.

Comment: OK, it was just a thought – for a public WiFi that should indeed be ruled out. Nevertheless, the admin can check the logs and maybe see something we can't. Fingers crossed!